Ovirt. Create domain POSIX Ceph
I am creating a posix domain, but there is an error mounting the directory:
2024-10-11 13:52:20,164+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.storageServer] Creating directory 
'/rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_' (storageServer:217)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,164+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.fileutils] Creating directory: 
/rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_ mode: None (fileUtils:214)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,164+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.mount] mounting 192.168.1.88:/ at 
/rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_ (mount:190)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,166+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/5) [api.host] START getAllVmStats() 
from=::1,57074 (api:31)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,167+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/5) [api.host] FINISH getAllVmStats return= 
{'status': {'code': 0, 'message': 'Done'}, 'statsList': (suppressed)} from=::1,57074 (api:37)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,293+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [IOProcessClient] (Global) Starting client 
(__init__:340)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,304+0300 INFO  (ioprocess/24690) [IOProcess] (Global) Starting ioprocess 
(__init__:465)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,305+0300 WARN  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.oop] Permission denied for directory: 
/rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_ with permissions:7 (outOfProcess:177)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,305+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.mount] unmounting /rhev/data- 
center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_ (mount:198)
2024-10-11 13:52:20,342+0300 ERROR (jsonrpc/4) [storage.storageServer] Could not connect to 
storage server (storageServer:75)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/fileSD.py", line 64, in 
 validateDirAccess
 getProcPool().fileUtils.validateAccess(dirPath)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/outOfProcess.py", line 178, in 
 validateAccess
 raise OSError(errno.EACCES, os.strerror(errno.EACCES))
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/storageServer.py", line 73, in 
connect_all
con.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/storageServer.py", line 241, in connect
six.reraise(t, v, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/storageServer.py", line 234, in connect
self.getMountObj().getRecord().fs_file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vdsm/storage/fileSD.py", line 75, in validateDirAccess
raise se.StorageServerAccessPermissionError(dirPath)
vdsm.storage.exception.StorageServerAccessPermissionError: Permission settings on the 
specified path do not allow access to the storage. Verify permission settings on the 
specified storage path.: 'path = /rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.1.88:_'
2024-10-11 13:52:20,343+0300 INFO  (jsonrpc/4) [storage.storagedomaincache] Invalidating 
storage domain cache (sdc:57)


How to fix it?

Given that is says raise OSError(errno.EACCES, os.strerror(errno.EACCES))  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied, then I would suspect that you are running it as an ordinary user when it requires root permissions.
